# What's the difference between BeginConnect and ConnectAsync?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

What is the difference between `BeginConnect` and `ConnectAsync`? Subsequently, what is the difference between `BeginDisconnect` and `DisconnectAsync`?

The [`ConnectAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538102%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) documentation states:

> "Begins an asynchronous request for a remote host connection."

The [`BeginConnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tad07yt6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) documentation **also** states:

> "Begins an asynchronous request for a remote host connection."

Both the [`DisconnectAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnectasync.aspx) and [`BeginDisconnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.begindisconnect.aspx) also state the same thing:

> "Begins an asynchronous request to disconnect from a remote endpoint."

What's the difference between those method pairs and which one should be used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Socket.ConnectAsync provides SocketAsyncEventArgs as a parameters which contains a lot more information compared to 3 params provided by BeginConnect. Also I know that ConnectAsync introduced later than BeginConnect and solves some issues related to timeouts (cannot remember the source of this discussion now). Prefer ConnectAsync when possible (though it requires min .NET 2.0 SP1).

There is a catch with ConnectAsync about the callbacks. If this is of concern, here are the discussions about it: [Stack overflow when using the System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AcceptAsync model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954668/stack-overflow-when-using-the-system-net-sockets-socket-acceptasync-model) and [AsyncCallBack CompletedSynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372053/asynccallback-completedsynchronously)

There is no support for BeginConnect method in Silverlight (only ConnectAsync is supported) so that may be another concern if you intend to develop client side Silverlight applications.

Also the patterns used in two approaches are different. Here is the discussion: [Is there any performance difference between Begin* and *Async for sockets in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202608/is-there-any-performance-difference-between-begin-and-async-for-sockets-in-net)

Comment: I disagree. Prefer the BeginXXX unless performance is absolutely critical. The XXXAsync API is considerably harder to implement and offers little performance benefit unless writing a server that must service many thousands of connected clients.

Comment: There is no support for Socket.BeginConnect in Silverlight, you may guess why.

Comment: Unless writing specifically for Silverlight, I stand by my answer. The BeginXXXX API is considerably easier to implement that XXXXAsync.

Comment: I've always used ConnectAsync and similar so cant really comment on that.

Answer (score 12):

The XXXXAsync methods were introduced because they reduce the amount of memory thrashing that occurs when servers have *many* connected clients. Coupled with [pooling described in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb517542.aspx), using this API considerably reduces the amount of work GC has to perform when compared to the older BeginXXX API.

The [docs say the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968780.aspx):

> The main feature of these enhancements is the avoidance of the repeated allocation and synchronization of objects during high-volume asynchronous socket I/O. The Begin/End design pattern currently implemented by the System.Net.Sockets.Socket class requires a System.IAsyncResult object be allocated for each asynchronous socket operation.

So, unless you're writing a server for many thousands of connected clients, I wouldn't bother with XXXXAsync. The API is considerably harder to implement and of little gain to anything other than enterprise level services.

Comment: when I try to reuse the socket the subsequent connections fail with the "Async family" calls and the "Begin family" calls... can you shed some light on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762276/reuse-asynchronous-socket-subsequent-connect-attempts-fail