# Why doesn't TcpClient.BeginConnect result's AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne return false if the listening service is down?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcpclient

I am making a connection to a service i created on another server via:

```
using (var clientSocket = new TcpClient())
{
    ...
    //Connect async
    var result = clientSocket.BeginConnect(hostIP, portNumber, null, null);

    //Wait for connection up to our timeout
    if (!result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
    {
        //This is NEVER run
        throw new Exception("Connection timed out.");
    }

    //It makes it here but shouldn't!
}
```

If the other server is up but the service that listens on the port is down, this still returns true! *(And if the server is down, it does properly throw the exception)*

Why?

How do I make it fail if the service is down (and thus nothing's listening on that port)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that there's no way to have it fail if there's nothing listening. Instead, you can use a `ReadTimeout` to handle the error of nothing listening on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the newer `ConnectAsync` method instead which even allows you to supply a `CancellationToken` in case you require your client-connecting task to abort prematurely.

```
using (var clientSocket = new TcpClient())
{
    //Connect async and wait for connection up to our timeout
    if (!clientSocket.ConnectAsync(hostIP, portNumber).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
    {
        throw new Exception("Connection timed out.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this actually do something different or is it internally the same as BeginConnect?

Comment: The `ConnectAsync` is simply a more modern way of connecting to a socket client asynchronously, whereas `BeginConnect` seems to be more of a legacy method. See a more detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5765032/633098