# Why HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse() completes synchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, c#-4.0

I'm testing ASP.NET (.NET 4) web-application under high load and have found that under some conditions `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse()` completes synchronously w/o throwing any exceptions.

After running the following code in multiple ASP.NET threads under high-load I've found "WEBREQUEST COMPLETED SYNC!" message in logs.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var result = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(internalCallback, userState);
if (result.CompletedSynchronously)
{
    Trace.Error("WEBREQUEST COMPLETED SYNC!");
}
```

Pay attention that:

1. In case thread pool capacity is reached an InvalidOperationException is thrown
2. In case error occurs during connection corresponding exception is thrown

In my case there are no exceptions!

I've decompiled System.Net assembly and found that it is really possible under some conditions. But I didn't understand what these conditions mean (`System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, bool forcedsubmit)`):

```
if (this.m_Free && this.m_WriteDone && !forcedsubmit && (this.m_WriteList.Count == 0 || request.Pipelined && !request.HasEntityBody && (this.m_CanPipeline && this.m_Pipelining) && !this.m_IsPipelinePaused))
{
  this.m_Free = false;
  needReConnect = this.StartRequest(request, true);
  if (needReConnect == TriState.Unspecified)
  {
    flag = true;
    this.PrepareCloseConnectionSocket(ref returnResult);
    this.Close(0);
  }
}
```

When & why is this possible?

Comment: look the [AysncCallBack CompletedSynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372053/asynccallback-completedsynchronously) will tell you what common partter of async loop complete in synchronously when your callback is in same thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found this for `CompletedSynchronously` propperty
***Use this property to determine if the asynchronous operation completed synchronously. For example, this property can return true for an asynchronous I/O operation if the I/O request was small.***
[HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously.aspx)

**EDIT:-** i suspect that the response might be getting cached. therefore try to stop caching of the response by using `request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(/*caching type*/);`

Comment: Usefull, but not an answer +1

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert +1 But I expect a reference to decompiled code or article w/ details when exactly it is possible. "Small" is not a criteria.

Comment: @ParvSharma Server returns Cache-Control: no-cache header. So, caching won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it is that async methods complete synchronously in 3 scenarios:

The operation could be completed very quickly - and so was executed synchronously to avoid the overhead of managing an asynchronous operation.

The underlying implementation - or operating system - doesn't support the Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) in that scenario.

The operation was CPU-bound and could be completed without blocking.

(reasons taken from c# in a nutshell J.Albahari & B.Albahari).

Comment: Thanks. But I need more details especially for HttpWebRequst or links to code.